# Dynamically loading data to a table and using datatable to paginate

Tags: jquery, datatable, pagination

I am using DataTable plugin for table pagination. I Dynamically load rows to my table and then use DataTable to paginate. When I hard code the entries those are added to the pagination view as expected. But the dynamically created part does not.

```
function loadAllDevices(){
    $.post("admin_devices_operations.jag",{
        operation:"getAllDevices"
    },function(data,status){    
        var objArray=JSON.parse(data);
        for(var i=0;i<objArray.length;i++){
            var newTable=document.getElementById('example');    
            var object=objArray[i];
            var newRow=document.createElement('tr');    
            for(var property in object){    
                alert(object[property]);
                var td=document.createElement('td');    
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(object[property]));    
                newRow.appendChild(td);
            }    
            newTable.appendChild(newRow);
        }
    });            
    oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    });        
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be helpful if you include an example of the starting tables HTML - from a quick look at your code it occurs to me that you could potentially be adding the new rows outside of the tbody.

Examining the DOM using Firebug or developer tools should either confirm or rule this out.